# formidable Express 500 TypeError: Cannot call method 'complete' of undefined

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to upload files with NodeJS, I've tried the most common multipart libraries, but can't get it work.

When I send the file I didn't get anything just a 500 error that doesn't exist method called complete. I tried a similar module alone and it work well. Is possible to have some var crashing? I made some console.log, util, and I didnt get anything of the variable form.

This is a piece of code. If you have any brilliant idea to try to solve this and you need more code, feel free to ask it!

```
 var express       = require('express');
 var form          = require('formidable');
    
 var app = module.exports = express.createServer(
   express.favicon()
   , express.bodyParser()
   , express.cookieParser()
   , express.session({secret: 'topsecret'})
   , everyauth.middleware()
   , express.router(routes)
 );


app.configure(function(){

  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({secret: "aiudhasiudj12" }));
  app.use(everyauth.middleware());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
  app.use(form({ keepExtensions: true }));

});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true })); 
});

 everyauth.everymodule
   .findUserById( function (userId, callback) {

   Login.findLocalByEmail([userId], function (error, results) {
     callback(null, { userId: userId, data: results});
   });
 });

 everyauth.facebook...

 [...]

 app.get('/la', function(req, res){
  res.send('<form action="la" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">'
    + '<p>Image: <input type="file" name="image" /></p>'
    + '<p><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>'
    + '</form>');

    //console.log(util.inspect(form, true, null));
});

 app.post('/la', function(req, res) {

  console.log(util.inspect(req.form, true, null));
  
  req.form.complete(function(err, fields, files) {
    
    console.log(fields);
    console.log(files);
    
    if(err) {
      next(err);
    } else {
      
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Express includes connect, that includes formidable.

All you have to do is use the bodyParser and check for "req.body", which should contain all fields of the form.

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices.

1. If you want to use `req.form`, you need to use https://github.com/dandean/express-form middleware.
2. But, assuming that you actually want to use `formidable`, the correct code you write inside your request handler would be as following.

   ```
   var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
   form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
     res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
     res.write('received upload:\n\n');
     res.end(sys.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));
   });
   ```

Comment: I try to use formidable but browser never ends, and never throughs form.parse function. I code a console.log after form definition and my response was: `{ error: null,
  ended: false,
  maxFieldsSize: 2097152,
  keepExtensions: false,
  uploadDir: '/tmp',
  encoding: 'utf-8',
  headers: null,
  type: null,
  bytesReceived: null,
  bytesExpected: null,
  _parser: null,
  _flushing: 0,
  _fieldsSize: 0 }` Any idea?!

Answer (score 0):

If your file input name in your html form is "image", then you need to check "req.files.image". Try the following:

```
console.log('File name: ' + req.files.image.name);
```